# Would like to split string with all different long part from last to first

Tags: c#, string, split, numbers

Example :

input : "1234567890"

OutPut :(if we want in part of 4,3,etc..) 7890,456,123, we could ask give us part like 5 4 3 1 etc

Answer (score 1):

Our requirement was different than usual and so this might help someone

I would like to answer what if we want to cut string from last..?

**Example** :

**input** : "1234567890"

**OutPut** : 7890,456,123

**Get the result statement** : string[] dt = "1234567890".SplitIt(new int[] { 4, 3, 6 }).ToArray();

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitIt(this string str, int[] chunkLength)
        {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) throw new ArgumentException();
        int i = str.Length;
        for (int j = 0; j < chunkLength.Length; j++)
        {
            if (chunkLength[j] < 1) throw new ArgumentException();
            if (i - chunkLength[j] < 0)
            {
                chunkLength[j] = i;
            }               
            yield return str.Substring(i - chunkLength[j], chunkLength[j]);
            i -= chunkLength[j];
        }
    }
```